# If $f:\,V\longrightarrow W$ preserves bilinear form then $f$ is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, bilinear-form

Let $V$ and $W$ be $n$ dimensional vector spaces on $\mathbb R$ with bilinear forms $\langle,\rangle_V:\, V\times V\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ and $\langle,\rangle_W:\, W\times W\longrightarrow\mathbb R$. Suppose a bijective map $f:\,V\longrightarrow W$ satisfies
\begin{align}
\big<f(u),f(v)\big>_W\,=\,\langle u,v\rangle_V,\ \forall\,u,v\in V.\tag1
\end{align}
Moreover, suppose $V$ has an orthonormal basis with respect to $\langle,\rangle_V$, say, $\mathcal B=(e_1,\cdots,e_n)$.

> Here, $\mathcal B$ is orthonormal basis means forall $i=1,\cdots,n$,
> $$\langle e_i,e_i\rangle_V\,=\,\pm1\ \text{ and } \ \langle e_i,e_j\rangle_V\,=\,0,\ j\ne i.$$

> The Mazur–Ulam theorem states that if $\langle,\rangle_V,\,\langle,\rangle_W$ are inner products then $f$ must be linear, moreover its representation matrix is orthogonal.

My wonder is if this theorem is true for bilinear forms that not needed to be inner product, like considered in this discussion. Here my answer :

First, we have for any $u,v\in V$,
\begin{align*}
\langle u,v\rangle_V\,&=\,\left<\sum_{i=1}^n u_ie_i\,,\sum_{i=1}^n v_ie_i \right>_V
\\ &=\,\sum_{i=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^n u_iv_j\big<e_i,e_j\big>_V
\\ &=\,\begin{bmatrix}
u_1 & \cdots & u_n
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\big<e_1,e_1\big> & \cdots & \big<e_1,e_n\big>
\newline \vdots & \ddots & \vdots
\newline \big<e_n,e_1\big> & \cdots & \big<e_n,e_n\big>
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
\,v_1 \, \\ \vdots \\ v_n
\end{bmatrix} 
\\ &=\,\big[u\big]_{\mathcal B}^\top\eta \big[v\big]_{\mathcal B}.\tag2
\end{align*}
Next, since $f$ is bijective, $f(\mathcal B)$ is also orthonormal basis of $W$. Thus for any $v\in V$, there exists $t_1,\dots, t_n\in\mathbb R$ such that
\begin{align}
f(v)\,=\,t_1f(e_1)+\cdots+ t_n f(e_n)\tag3
\end{align}
this implies $\forall\, i=1,\dots,n $
\begin{align}
\big<f(v),f(e_i)\big>_W\,&=\,\big<t_1f(e_1)+\cdots+ t_n f(e_n),f(e_i)\big>_W
\\ &=\,t_1\big<f(e_1),f(e_i)\big>_W+\cdots+t_n\big<f(e_n),f(e_i)\big>_W
\\ &=\,t_1\big<e_1,e_i\big>_V+\cdots+t_n\big<e_n,e_i\big>_V
\\ &=\,t_i\langle e_i,e_i\rangle_V. \tag4
\end{align}
On the other hand, we have
\begin{align}
\big<f(v),f(e_i)\big>_W\,&=\,\langle v,e_i\rangle_V
\\ &=\,\big<v_1e_1+\cdots+v_ne_n,e_i\big>_V
\\ &=\,v_1\langle e_1,e_i\rangle_V+\cdots+v_n\langle e_n,e_i\rangle_V
\\ &=\,v_i\langle e_i,e_i\rangle_V.\tag5
\end{align}
From (4) and (5), we deduce $t_i=v_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$. Therefore
\begin{align}
f\big(v_1e_1+\cdots+v_ne_n \big)\,=\,v_1f(e_1)+\cdots v_nf(e_n).
\end{align}
Therefore, $f$ is linear. Moreover, if
\begin{align}
A\,=\,\begin{bmatrix}
\big[f(e_1)\big]&\cdots&\big[f(e_n)\big]
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
then $A^\top\eta A=\eta$.

Is my proof correct ? I hope to receive opinions from people. Thanks.

Comment: It is unclear to me why $f(\mathcal{B})$ needs to be a basis. From $(1)$ we know that they are "orthonormal", but not that they span the entire space.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven do you think my problem needs some more assumption ? Unless, in my opinion,  consider the equation
$$ a_1f(e_1)+\cdots+a_nf(e_n)=0$$
we have for any $i=1,\cdots,n,$
\begin{align}
0\,&=\,\big<0,f(e_i)\big>_W
\\ &=\,\big<  a_1f(e_1)+\cdots+a_nf(e_n),f(e_i)\big>_W
\\ &=\,a_1\big<f(e_1),f(e_i)\big>_W+\cdots+a_n\big<f(e_n),f(e_i)\big>_W
\\ &=\,a_1\langle e_1,e_i\rangle_V+\cdots+a_n\langle e_n,e_i\rangle_V
\\ &=\,a_i\langle e_i,e_i\rangle_V
\end{align}
which will implies $a_i=0$. Therefore $f(\mathcal B)$ is linearly independent.

Comment: I am not saying you need more assumptions. I just did not see how to get that they form a basis (you wrote that it follows from $f$ being bijective, which did not make much sense to me). Apart from the basis thing it looks pretty good to me.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven yeah I need the assumption $f$ is bijective, since $f(\mathcal  B)$ may has less than $n$ vector if $f$ isn't

Comment: That's not true. You literally proved in your last comment that this does not happen and you did not use at all that $f$ is bijective. One will get aposteriori that $f$ is bijective, but one does not need to assume it.

Comment: You said merely that $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is a bilinear form. But really, do you want it to also be symmetric and non-degenerate (i.e a pseudo-inner product)? Othewise such an ‘orthonormal’ basis need not exist. Also, you don’t need to assume $f$ is bijective (see the following PhySE answer of mine for a proof: [Fixing non-calculus proof that Lorentz transformations are linear](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/647459/203278)).

Comment: @peek-a-boo yes, you know me quite well

Comment: … I just realized that in my answer there I left as an exercise that $f$ (there called $T$) sends an ON-basis to an ON-basis. But I think you get the idea: it first sends the ON basis to an ON *set*, and ON sets are linearly independent (by your comment above… which shows that the usual inner product statement and proof goes through in greater generality), but now we have $n=\dim W$ of them so it is a basis for $W$. (Also, I phrased it for $T:V\to V$ but clearly the same proof goes through for general $T:V\to W$ with $\dim V=\dim W<\infty$).

Comment: @peek-a-boo do you study much on relativity theory ?